# Can't put item on ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I dont understand why it doesnt show up the first and the second items in the ActionBar... All three appear on the OverflowBar.

Cumps

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        tools:context="com.example.projx.xActivity_1" >       

      <item
        android:id="@+id/action_ref"
        android:title="@string/action_ref"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

     <item
        android:id="@+id/action_infpe"
        android:title="@string/action_infpe"
        android:orderInCategory="2"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"/>

       <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>

</menu>
```

Comment: well is there room in the ationbar for them because if not then `ifRoom` would cause that

Comment: You may have to use "Always" instead of "ifRoom" in android:showAsAction

Comment: You are using `app:showAsAction` for the last item but `android:showAsAction` for the first two ones. I guess that's the problem.

Comment: i had to use `app:showAsAction` and it worked. Thanks a lot, don't know how i didn't saw that!

Comment: See here

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20817740/cant-see-search-in-action-bar